# How to get or edit an already registered user in my tenant on Azure B2C

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a tenant in Azure AD B2C, I have set my policies, and scopes. In Xamarin, I have already set up my tenant properties, and I can successfully sign in or sign up with my app using MSAL.
Now, once I have already signed up to my up, I want to send some data from a form my app to the user data in AD B2C - Users. Is this done with Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph. I searched in documentations but there is nothing that points towards what I am trying to achieve.

*(I've tried the Microsoft Graph method but on every attempt and sample on github it tells me that the token is invalid, even if I reaquired it)*

Comment: If I recall correctly, you'll need to do the updates in your back-end by using the client credentials flow. The B2C documentation has a section on using the Graph API.

Comment: @juunas Right! Guess I didn't take it in consideration at the moment before making the question because I wanted to see if there were some other existent approaches..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Manage users programmatically, you must use the Azure AD Graph API (Not the Microsoft Graph API). This is well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications

> For automated, continuous tasks, you should use some type of service account that you provide with the necessary privileges to perform management tasks. In Azure AD, you can do this by registering an application and authenticating to Azure AD. This is done by using an Application ID that uses the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant. In this case, the application acts as itself, not as a user, to call the Graph API.

Here you can find a GitHub sample that does exactly what you ask: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet

Given that you're talking about a mobile app, you should host a backend service that receives the info from your user and then uses client credentials to communicate with the Azure AD Graph API. DON'T USE client credentials directly from you mobile app!

Comment: Great info. right there! But to what you mentioned about hosting the backend and taking care of the client credentials, I came up with the question; wouldn't it be better to take use of the User Attributes on Azure AD B2C Policies? I mean, I make sure that in the SignInOrSignUp policy (for instance) to return the ID of the user, then, with that ID I store all the wanted data at a database with te required fields that I want, and use that database within my app.

Comment: Of course you could use a database to store such additional informations (so, outside AAD B2C). But if you want them to be persisted in AAD B2C, you have to write them either by a custom policy or via Azure AD Graph API